# How do you get mapserver for windows work on 64 bit microsoft 2008 server?

Tags: windows, mapserver

How do you get mapserver for windows work on 64 bit microsoft 2008 server? I tried installing it and the apache server said it started but it would not serve even a basic html file.  I have 32 bit enabled on the server as well as cgi.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Supply more info: which installer did you use? How did you start apache? How did you test apache? Check the apache logfiles: what do they say?

Comment: We definitely need more information about the error you're getting. I use mapserver on 64bit windows 2008 server all the time without problems, so there might be an issue with your apache configuration rather than mapserver itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as pre-built 64 bit Windows binaries support is concerned, the answer is to either fetch binaries from http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/ and roll your own or pay Jeff McKenna at http://www.gatewaygeomatics.com/ for his 64 bit MS4W build.

Comment: The link is invalid...

Answer (score 1):

It is old, but to guide new comers :

[GISInternals](http://gisinternals.com/) is providing latest releases (both 32-bit and 64-bit) installs on windows.